# Can we show the 5 next upcoming events inside Calender view's app part

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, events

i am working on sharepoint online team site collection. now i got the following requirement:-

1. we need to add a sharepoint calendar.
2. then inside the site home page, to show a customized calendar view which will only show the next 5 upcoming events inside Calendar view .

now i was thinking of doing the following, on paper these steps should work fine:-

1. Add an app part inside my home page for the Calendar.
2. Then edit the Calendar view, and define the following:-

   - inside the list view filter, to only show the calendar's events which have start date greater than or equal today date and time.
   - sort by start date ascending.
   - limit the list view to only 5.

now this did not work for the following reasons:-

1. inside the Calendar list view, i can not define an item limit option. and seems the Calendar view will always show all the events...
2. i can not filter the list view based on the Start date...

so not sure if there is a workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: If it does not need to look like a calendar, just the next five events, then just create a Standard view. That will have the options you need.

Comment: @MikeSmith-MCT-MVP now i want to show it as a calendar, i know when using standard view i have more options but in my case i want the calendar view to show the 5 next events... not sure if this is achievable or not..

Answer (score 2):

1. In calendar view, we cannot filter by Start Time column directly.

There is a workaround for the issue.

We can create another column with “Date and Time” column type. And copy the value of the Start Time column to the new column. Then filter by the new column in calendar view.

2. In calendar view, we cannot define item limit directly.

There is a workaround for the issue.

We can define the scope to display the less items. We can use the week scope to reduce the items to display.
[image]

Comment: for point 1 will try the workaround, but for the second point i do not think scoping will help in my case... as the 5 next upcomming events might not be in the upcommin week or month....

Comment: If you do not want to use the scope in your case, then we cannot define the item limit in the calendar view. Or you could consider using the standard view to display the events.

Comment: now i do not want to use standard view, i want to use the Calendar view..i know standard view will allow me to filter and sort the way i want,,, but this is not what i am looking for

Comment: Then we cannot define the item limit in the calendar view.